# Cookie in request is always "None" using nextjs and fetch

Tags: cookies, next.js, fetch-api

Hi im trying to send CORS request to my api with cookie that contains authorization key. However no matter what the cookie value is in the browser inside request i always see that the value is "None"

So far i did:

- I have configured my backend to accept cookies from my app
- Added "credentials": "include" to my fetch options
- Set the cookie options to: sameSite: "none", secure: true and value to my key.

I'm sure cookie is sent with the request but the value isn't correct. Im using nextjs ^13.2 and fetch

Comment: Cookies don't just get their value set to the string 'None', so you should be able to search your code-base for this string to find out what's doing this.